# "under the ten minutes" vs "under ten minutes"

Tags: meaning, definite-articles, time

By the end of Chapter 5 of *The Hound of the Baskervilles* by Arthur Conan Doyle, there is a usage that I have never seen before: "under the ten minutes".

The context:

> Until we got three-quarters down Regent Street. Then my gentleman threw up the trap, and he cried that I should drive right away to Waterloo Station as hard as I could go. I whipped up the mare and we were there under the ten minutes.

Is "under the ten minutes" exactly the same as "under ten minutes"? Or do they have different shades of meanings?

Comment: It's tempting to interpret [this Google 4-gram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=under+the+ten+minutes&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cunder%20the%20ten%20minutes%3B%2Cc0) (for "under the ten minutes") merely as a popularity marker for the Holmes books. But 'just under the hour' seems to have been in fairly unpredictable use over the decades.

Comment: Context needed.  Was 10 minutes previously established as a deadline?

Comment: This post was created over a year ago. They probably don't care anymore...

Answer (score -1):

It's just a way to emphasize that it took no more than ten minutes. Conceptually "ten minutes" is being used as a single unit, except there is no distinct name for ten minutes like there is for 15 minutes - the quarter or 60 minutes - the hour, so he's using "the ten minutes".

He's saying that they got there pretty fast - he feels/states that he rode there in under 10 minutes.

There are similar expressions in modern English including:

- You're fired! I want you to clear out your desk within *the* hour.
- The train will arrive within *the* the next quarter-hour.

Comment: "the ten minutes" sounds pretty archaic if you ask me.

Comment: Are you surmising or have you heard this expression?  Doyle wrote this 120 years ago.  I wonder if this kind of talk is still around in the UK; it's unheard of in the US.

Comment: You're right, I'm guessing. I haven't heard it in daily speech, movies, tv-shows or read it. But, of course I don't speak to everyone so some people may still use it. There's nothing wrong with the expression, but it's not very common. At least in my opinion. So "archaic" is perhaps a bit much given that it's only a 120 years old.

Comment: It seems to me that the cab driver is emphasising the speed and meant "under the ten minutes *that it usually takes to travel that distance*"

Comment: Also ' ... in just under the hour' uses the 'familiar' conceptualising of the good old hour unit.

Comment: Where is "the quarter" used to mean a quarter of an hour? I've heard it to mean a quarter of a year (e.g., "the company's profits declined in the last quarter") or with an indefinite article (e.g., "it's a quarter to three"), but never in a sentence such as your last example.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan I must have "adopted" that expression from Norwegian. "kvarter" means 15 minutes, whereas year-quarter is "kvartal". Not unusual at all to hear people use "kvarter" (15 min), but you're probably right about English.

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин "A quarter past (or to) the hour" is used all the time. What is not used is "_The_ quarter past". If speaking of an elapsed time we sometimes use the definite article but only if there was a deadline or estimate involved. For instance someone might borrow a car for a short but urgent trip promising to be back in fifteen minutes. They could then be said to return the car "within the quarter of an hour" if succesful" but _of an hour_ would be needed as well.